# problem with extracting a value in an html response with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I have a problem with extracting a value in an html response with jmeter, what regular expression should I use to be able to extract myself: client_id% 3D27d15a22-4f44-469a-8480-f3d19825e8e8 ?, without client_id% 3D

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-like structure from the response the relevant regular expression would be something like:

```
([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-]([A-Fa-f0-9]){12})
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [How to validate GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) using Regular Expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-guid-globally-unique-identifier-using-regular-expression/)

Comment: thank you very much!! but if I were to extract nonce% 3Dw0vT_l3GLDvAXKBT0WEVRvolcaq-8Dg8UuBuwB1It3Y
this too without nonce% 3D